# Pentaho: re-use logic within a transformation

Tags: pentaho

How do I re-use a piece of logic within a transformation?

Right now the transformation lookes like this:

```
Read file 1 --> Step 1 --> Step 2 -->  ... --> Step n --> Write file 1
Read file 2 --> Step 1 --> Step 2 -->  ... --> Step n --> Write file 2
...
Read file 50 --> Step 1 --> Step 2 -->  ... --> Step n --> Write file 50
```

The transformation logic (`Step 1 to Step n`) is the same for all input files.

What I want to have is:

```
Read file 1 --> Call Transformation logic --> Write file 1
Read file 2 --> Call Transformation logic --> Write file 2
...
Read file 50 --> Call Transformation logic --> Write file 50

Transformation logic:= Step 1 --> Step 2 -->  ... --> Step n
```

I know there is the *Mapping (sub-transformation)* step.
However I would end up with two .ktr files: one for the parent transformation (containing file input, sub-transformation call and file output), and one for the sub-transformation (containing the steps 1 to n).

I do not want to split the transformation into two files only for the purpose of re-using the Steps 1 to n. So how do I use the functionality of the *Mapping (sub-transformation)* step without ending up with two .ktr files?

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Please add the code for the logic in the transformation and references where you are based upon. This way others can help you in a more direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, we have loop container where every steps in loop container will execute until loop end.

But In PDI, we don't have any loop container. You must have to use two transformation to full fill your requirements. **Or** you can use JavaScript step to write your condition if possible.